# Why Doesn't $2^{1/n}= 1/(2^n)$

Tags: exponential-function, fractions

Take $2^{1/n}$. Since $1/n$ can be simplified as $n^{-1}$, the original term can become $2^{n^{-1}}$. The exponents can then be multiplied to result in $2^{-n}$ which is $1/(2^n)$. However it is obvious that

$2^{1/n} \ne 1/(2^n)$

because the first item approaches 1 as $n \rightarrow \infty$ but the second item approaches 0. What is wrong with the logic I used to simplify the first into the second that causes this discrepancy?

Comment: $2^{1/n}=\sqrt[n]2$

Comment: I get that, but how come $1/n$ can't become $n^{-1}$ and follow the logic I used?

Comment: $1/n = n^{-1} \ne -n$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exponents multiply in the sense that $$(a^b)^c = a^{bc}.$$ They do not multiply in the sense that $$a^{(b^c)} \ne a^{bc}.$$

Comment: I would say a more precise way to say it is that $a^{(b^c)}$ does not **generally** equal $a^{bc}$.

Answer (score 1):

The order in which you do the operations is vital here.
Unlike addition and multiplication, exponentiation is not associative:
$$a^{(b^{\large c})} \neq \left(a^b\right)^c$$
for "most" values of $a$, $b$, and $c$.

It is true that $2^{1/n} = 2^{n^{\large -1}}$,
but that's because $2^{n^{\large -1}}$ means $2^{(n^{\large -1})}$.
As you saw for yourself, $2^{(n^{\large -1})}$
is not the same thing at all as $\left(2^n\right)^{-1}$.

Comment: I like the question and I like this answer. It's pretty rare that something useful isn't associative.

Answer (score 0):

The exponents cannot be multiplied, as the first exponent is raised to the second. You are right that $(x^a)^b=x^{ab}$, but you do not have $x^{a^b}=x^{ab}$, as $a^b \neq ab$.